# How to remove caption from Image

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, asp.net, .net

I have used the following code to Display a processing image while the submit button is clicked in asp.net, but after I wrote this code a caption tag has added automatically resulting in showing the image in the top of the page, now I want to remove this tag or fix this problem, each time I remove it comes back automatically.
Code

```
script type="text/javascript">
function check()
{
$("#checking").show();
}
</script>
OnClientClick="check();" 
<div id="checking" style="display:none;position: fixed;top: 0;left: 0;width: 100%;height: 100%;background: #f4f4f4;z-index: 99;">
  <div class="text" style="position: absolute;top: 45%;left: 0;height: 100%;width: 100%;font-size: 18px;text-align: center;">
    <center>
      <img src="load.gif" alt="Loading">
    </center>
    Checking Please Wait! 
    <Br>Meanwhile Please 
      <b style="color: red;">BE ONLINE
      </b>
      </div>
  </div>
```

**The following code has added automatically**

```
 <caption>
          <img alt="Loading" src="load.gif"></img>
 </caption>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`unwrap()`](https://api.jquery.com/unwrap/) to remove the parents of the set of matched elements from the DOM, leaving the matched elements in their place.

```js
$('img').unwrap('caption');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<center>
<caption>
          <img alt="Loading" src="load.gif" />
 </caption>
 </center>
Checking Please Wait! <Br>Meanwhile Please <b style="color: red;">BE ONLINE</b>
```